# Execute JavaScript code inside Python/PyMongo map/reduce

Tags: mapreduce, pymongo

I need to execute dynamically created map/reduce javascript functions inside python code on MongoDB ( in python I create strings-javascript code for map/reduce). How to call those strings( javascript functions)  inside Python code and execute ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [pymongo.code.Code](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.6/api/pymongo/code.html) where you instantiate `Code` objects using your Javascript code as a single string argument in the following way:

```
maper = Code('function () { for (var key in this) { emit(key, 1); }}')
reducer = Code('function(key, values) { return 1; }')
result = collection.map_reduce(maper, reducer, 'results')
```

Where `result` is a `Collection` instance that will contain the results of your map/reduce.I have put some dummy code within both `mapper` and `reducer` to illustrate the point. You can consult [Map/Reduce Example](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.3/examples/map_reduce.html) in the `pymongo` documentation for more information.